# Dataflow batch template provided by google does not work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, avro

I want to run the sample in [1].
However, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["null",{"type":"int","logicalType":"date"}]: 1990-01-01 (field=birthday)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish (DirectRunner.java:353)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish (DirectRunner.java:321)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run (DirectRunner.java:216)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run (DirectRunner.java:67)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:317)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:303)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.Test.run (Test.java:299)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.Test.main (Test.java:232)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["null",{"type":"int","logicalType":"date"}]: 1990-01-01 (field=birthday)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeField (GenericDatumWriter.java:223)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord (GenericDatumWriter.java:210)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion (GenericDatumWriter.java:131)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write (GenericDatumWriter.java:83)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write (GenericDatumWriter.java:73)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder.encode (AvroCoder.java:317)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.encode (Coder.java:136)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.encodeToSafeStream (CoderUtils.java:82)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.encodeToByteArray (CoderUtils.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.encodeToByteArray (CoderUtils.java:51)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.clone (CoderUtils.java:141)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MutationDetectors$CodedValueMutationDetector.<init> (MutationDetectors.java:115)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MutationDetectors.forValueWithCoder (MutationDetectors.java:46)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ImmutabilityCheckingBundleFactory$ImmutabilityEnforcingBundle.add (ImmutabilityCheckingBundleFactory.java:112)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ParDoEvaluator$BundleOutputManager.output (ParDoEvaluator.java:301)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue (SimpleDoFnRunner.java:267)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$900 (SimpleDoFnRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output (SimpleDoFnRunner.java:413)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output (SimpleDoFnRunner.java:401)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$TypedRead$3.processElement (BigQueryIO.java:1139)
```

For reference, the version of avro is 1.10.1
Is there any solution?

[1]https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/v2/bigquery-to-parquet/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/templates/BigQueryToParquet.java

Comment: What's your avro schema you used?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I'm new to avro so I don't know how to answer your question.
Where can I check to answer the question?

Comment: Of cource i don't know where your schema exists too. It is known issue that apache beam occur.
I think redesigning your "birthday" date type to int or string does help.

Comment: I'm using Bigquery table data.
I understood that this is a known issue.
When I reference a table that doesn't use the DATE, TIME, and RECORD types, I've verified that it works.

How can I refer to a table including DATE type, TIME type and RECORD type with apachebeam and output it in parquet format?
Please let me know if you know.

Comment: The schema is logged here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/ca0d47e23e6dcd795d1f5996eb82f9bdc073e3bb/v2/bigquery-to-parquet/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/templates/BigQueryToParquet.java#L218

Comment: Can you please provide the entire stack trace? Without the rest of the stack trace it is not actually clear where this error occurred. Was it in reading the BQ data? Writing the Parquet?

Comment: I added the entire stack trace to the post. Please have a look there.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug.

1. The Avro schema is retrieved from BigQuery and it indicates that the field `birthday` should be a nullable integer that represents a date.
2. The actual data when written is a string or date (cannot tell from the output).

I browsed [Avro's code](https://github.com/apache/avro/search?l=Java&q=UnresolvedUnionException) and it seems that exception is only thrown when *writing* data, not reading. So it appears this happening during the write to Parquet, perhaps because the `GenericRecord` loaded from the Avro files has converted the `birthday` field so it is no longer an integer.

You may be able to work around this by avoiding the DATE type.